# How to check that ads are being played, before the real video plays?

Tags: watir

I am working on a site, which airs ads before the real video plays.

The business requirement is that the ads should play before the video plays.

I am Using watir for testing. can you help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you call a friend to check?

Comment: I am afraid, I cannot. Any suggestions on how I can test that the ads are playing. Also the ads are included in the flash player.

Comment: Is the page public? In that case please provide a link. If not, please provide sample HTML.

Comment: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xl4oqc_the-killing-joke_shortfilms

In the above url, there is an advertisement which plays for 24 seconds odd and then the real video plays.

So, using watir how can we check that the ad is playing?

Thanks a lot. I have someone to help.

Comment: I do not see the ad at the beginning. As far as I can see, it is flash movie, and Watir does not work with flash.

Comment: When I inspect element, and if I have to check for an event ex : event=ad-fill which is specified in the <script class = ' ad-fill' src =''>  </script>...

Then how can I check for the above.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate Sikuli   I've seen other threads where people were using it in combination with watir to work with things like flash.   However, since it works based on visual recognition, I expect it would not work at all with video (a changing image that might only be 'right' for a fraction of a second) while it is playing unless there is some aspect of the screen that is relatively static that could be used to know the video play is in progress.  See this [blog posting](http://www.software-testing.com.au/blog/2010/08/16/automating-flash-ajax-popups-and-more-using-ruby-watir-and-sikuli/) for more info